# Fedora 30: Cannot connect to university network

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, wifi, networkmanager

I am running Fedora 30 on an HP 14q-cy0004au with an rtl8723de. Networkmanager can well connect to other wifi networks - One on my android phone's hotspot, another personal hotspot device (JioFi), and tethered hotspot from friend's laptop. All of these use WPA2 PSK.

But unfortunately It doesn't connect to University WiFi AP - It isn't Eduroam. (Networkmanager tries for a minute. But only one of two bubbles in nm-applet stays green and after ~1 minute it fails)

Configuration for college AP:
  Auth: WPA2 Enterprise PEAP

2nd level Auth: MSCHAPV2

SSID: STUDENT

Domain: No domain

Ca-certs: Not required.

For information, Windows 10 & Android as old as 5.0 work just fine with it. I have also seen an Ubuntu PC connecting to it out of the box.

College network staff didn't respond when I asked about software configuration of AP so I cannot provide those details here.

Last time I tried with debian and results were same. When I tried with wpa_supplicant, wpa_suppicant debug output was same for college & personal AP but dhclient had failed to obtain ip address from college AP.

- What is the 'Secret sauce' that ubuntu might be using to connect to this network?
- Is there any alternative method to get it working with university wifi?
- Does it have anything to do with my wifi driver? The driver for my chipset rtl8723de isn't in kernel so I have compiled it. If there is something to do with driver, I'd try my luck with a USB adapter.

Update: I used a usb adapter and it is now just fine connecting to the network. I'd believe there is something wrong with official driver. I'd just leave this question open, expecting to know why it won't work with certain drivers.

Comment: It is very uncommon not to have a CA-cert specified in these networks. I assume Ubunutu, Android and Windows have a few official root certificates preinstalled and you will have to add them to Fedora manually. Best is if you double check the WiFi access FAQs for your university network again and search for the certificate it requires. Also domains are usually set nowadays. Check `/var/log/syslog` for hints and errors.

Comment: @Fiximan I bought a usb adapter and with it the network is connecting fine. Obviously the problem is with the driver. Thanks for taking time to answer.